# Loop through clipboard history?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way in AHK (preferrably v1) to loop through Window's clipboard history (the one that pops up upon pressing `Windows key` + `v`)? Something like...

```
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
    MsgBox, 4, , File number %A_Index% is %A_LoopField%.`n`nContinue?
    IfMsgBox, No, break
}
```

...but not line by line, but item by item?

Ultimately, I would like to use this to regularly and flexibly access the last couple of (text) clipboard items to fill in login forms, keyword lists etc.

Comment: have you tried other tools, e.g. Ditto? I'm not sure what u want is possible, since the Windows clipboard only stores the current contents, not history.

Comment: I guess you can call [`Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.gethistoryitemsasync), or more simply, just use [`OnClipboardChange()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/OnClipboardChange.htm) to keep track of your clipboard.